# Fetching data from multiple table of MS Access into datagrid view in vb.net

Tags: .net, database

Hello friends here is my code

```
connect()
        cmd.CommandText = "Select RegID,Name,EmailID,DOB,State,Nation,Contact1 As Contact,ParmanentAdd as Address,Religion,WillNo as WillNumber,Will from SelfInformation"
        cmd.Connection = cn
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
        tb.Clear()
        tb.Load(dr)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = tb
        cmd.Dispose()
        cn.Close()

        'family.........

connect()
        'cmd.CommandText = "Select RegID,FName As Father,MName As Mother,MStatus As Marital,Degree,Childran As Children,NOC As NumberOfChild from Faimly"
        'cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        'cmd.Connection = cn
        'dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
        'tb.Clear()
        'tb.Load(dr)
        'DataGridView1.DataSource = tb
        'cmd.Dispose()
        'cn.Close()
```

the data is only fetching the second table data in datagrid view .i want to load data from both the tables

please help

Answer (score 0):

You need to join two tables in `cmd.CommandText` and load it into DataGridView.

```
cmd.CommandText = "Select si.RegID,si.Name,si.EmailID,si.DOB,si.State,si.Nation,si.Contact1 As Contact, " & _
           "si.ParmanentAdd as Address,si.Religion,si.WillNo as si.WillNumber,si.Will," & _
           "f.FName as Father, f.MName as Mother, f.MStatus as Marital, f.Degree, f.Childran As Children, f.NOC As NumberOfChild " & _
           " FROM SelfInformation si, Family f WHERE si.RegID = f.RegID"
```